# How to check if an element exist in array of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

please I am trying to regroup the array based on the course. Instead of 0,1,2 etc. For example, check if "Elementary Economics" exist in all the array, then it should return the result of all the array elements that match "Elementary Economics".

```
student => [
  0 => [
       "name" => "John Doe", 
    "gender" => "Male",
    "department" => "Economics",
    "courses" => [
                   "Elementary Economics",
                   "Principle of Economics",
                   "Macro Economics"
                   "Money Market"
                  ]
     ], 
  1 => [
     "name" => "John Doe", 
    "gender" => "Male",
    "department" => "Economics",
    "courses" => [
                   "Advanced Economics",
                   "Principle of Economics",
                   "Micro Economics"
                   "Money Market"
                  ]
    ]
    2 => [
       "name" => "John Doe", 
    "gender" => "Male",
    "department" => "Economics",
    "courses" => [
                   "Elementary Economics",
                   "Principle of Economics",
                   "Macro Economics"
                   "Value Market"
                  ]
    ]

 ]
```

I want to group them by the course, I have tried to used **array_filter**, it didn't work as I intend or maybe I was doing it wrong.

```
$result = array_filter($student, function ($item) use ($student['courses']) {
                    return \in_array($item, $student['courses'], true);
                }, \ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: why don't you just loop over student array using foreach?

Comment: I looped through it, but that doesn't, but I need to group the array by course

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is it a single student or an array of students that you want to regroup?

Comment: Just as it is, I want to be for instance, if "Elementary Econonics" - display array that associate with it, if it is "Money Market" display only that.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I was able solve my issue by installing and using **array-group-by**

```
$ composer require mcaskill/php-array-group-by
```

```
$grouped = array_group_by( $student, "course" );
```

Comment: You could have done it without an external package as well.

Comment: No one was ready to help and I have limited time as I am hitting deadline to submit my assignment.

Comment: Fair enough. Just saying this but don't mind me. I had actually added a comment on your question but didn't bother to respond.